# Стабильность javascript

Tags: ajax, php, javascript

На js программирую совсем недавно и впечатление о нем складывается не самое приятное... Итак, с самого начала.

Проект пишется на связке php + js. Очень много чего подгружается с использованием AJAX. Всякие кнопочки, текстовые блоки, картинки и т.д. постоянно меняются + производятся всякие редиректы. Складывается такое ощущение, что иногда js как-то коряво прогружается, и, следовательно, коряво работает... Скажите, насколько это может соответствовать истине? Или нечего на зеркало пенять, все дело в ошибках? Мне действительно непонятно, в чем причина возникновения той или иной ошибки. Они появляются абсолютно непредвиденно и в случайные моменты времени. Как можно повысить стабильность работы?

Comment: Не все браузеры одинаково работают с некоторым кодом JavaScript. Поэтому надо постоянно тестировать работу на разных браузерах.

Comment: Я когда начинал писать на js тоже его тихо ненавидил, сейчас же это мой любимый язык, более того сейчас даже nodejs начал учить чтобы и сервер у меня был на нем ^^<br>
По теме - вы сами написали что пишете совсем недавно, а чего вы собственно хотели? Чтобы вы сразу писали качественный код? Увы так не бывает...<br>
Тестировать в разных браузерах, конечно, нужно но не надо сильно увлекаться.<br>
Кстати не смотря на то что язык интерпритируемый - большинство современных браузеров использует Just In Time коспиляцию, так что со скоростью виноваты скорее всего вы...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ощущение  создается потому, что веб-программирование это мешанина из кучи языков, разметок и технологий. Скорее всего проблема в ошибках, хочется, конечно, обвинить язык, программу, инструмент, но если вы пользуетесь популярными средствами - в 99% это ваша вина, ошибка, неправильно выстроенная архитектура(порождающая кучу несостыковок) или незнание инструментария. Пользуйтесь средствами отладки, научитесь локализовывать проблему, постоянно улучшайте архитектуру проекта и js(и любой другой язык, кроме пожалуй brainfuck-а) покажется вам отличным языком.=)

Comment: Я никого не обвиняю, успокойтесь =) Инструментарий я не знаю, это правда. Поэтому и спрашиваю совета

Comment: Да нет я описываю больше свою ситуацию, но думаю она подходит многим новичкам. Лично если волнует ошибки в js - юзайте <b>firebug</b>, отличная простая и в то же время мощная вещь. Без нее как без рук. Для php есть xdebug, но я сам все никак не соберусь его прикрутить

Comment: ддааааа уже разбираюсь с firebug. Спасибо огромнейшее всем

Comment: на самом деле для отладки подходит любая консоль разработчика...<br>
Лично мне больше всего нравится консоль GoogleChome т.к. работает быстрее ( тут не firebug виноват, а сама mazilla медленее чем GoogleChome )

Comment: Firebug есть и на Chrome его функционал, хоть и меньше, но все равно ИМХО лучше чем у хрома. Кстати я начинал лично с хромовского дебагера. Но все-таки тормознутость дебагера ведь не настолька критична. Конечному пользователю важен результат. Но с тормозами мазилы, конечно, спорить не буду)))